Complete groups
Recently, I have been studying complete groups, and I know that if a group $N$ is complete then for every short exact sequence $1 \rightarrow N \xrightarrow{f} G \xrightarrow{g} H \rightarrow 1$ of groups, we have $G = f(N)L$ for some $L \unlhd G$ such that $f(N) \cap L = \{e\}$. Does this characterize complete groups? Namely, I have the following question: if $N$ is a group such that for every short exact sequence $1 \rightarrow N \xrightarrow{f} G \xrightarrow{g} H \rightarrow 1$ of groups, we have $G = f(N)L$ for some $L \unlhd G$ such that $f(N) \cap L = \{e\}$, then does it imply that $N$ is a complete group? I am completely stuck with this question, please help me.

By embedding into the holomorph, you can see that your property on $N$ implies that $N$ has no outer automorphisms. I am not sure about trivial centre. In a counterexample, the centre would have to be a divisible abelian group, since otherwise you could extend $N$ nontrivially as a central product.

@Derek Holt, I understand that $Out(N) = 1$. Still, I could not understand the second paragraph you mentioned: "In a counterexample, the center would have to be a divisible abelian group since otherwise, you could extend N nontrivially as a central product", this part.  It would be helpful if you could kindly clarify my doubts.

Let $Z=Z(N)$. If $Z$ is not divisible then there is an abelian group $Y$ with $Z <Y$ such that $Z$ has no complement in $Y$. Then the central product $G$  of $N$ and $Y$ amalgamating $Z$ would not have your property because $Z$ would have no normal complement in $G$.

@Derek Holt, thank you very much, I understand it now clearly. I was wondering if we could get an example of a group $N$ such that $N$ is not complete and $N$ satisfies the above property.

You could try asking the question on mathoverflow, including a link to the question here.

@Derek Holt Okay, thank you very much.
